# Lexographically smallest path in a N*M grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I came across this in a recent interview.
We are given a N*M grid consisting of numbers and a path in the grid is the nodes you traverse.We are given a constraint that we can only move either right or down in the grid.So given this grid, we need to find the lexographically smallest path,after sorting it, to reach from top left to bottom right point of the grid

Eg. if grid is 2*2

4 3

5 1
then lexographically smallest path as per the question is "1 3 4".
How to do such problem? Code is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the path should be "4 3 1" rather than "1 3 4" since you start from the top left.

Comment: We have to sort the path and then print the lexographically smallest.Sorry, I will edit the question.

Comment: This question featured in a Quora post: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-toughest-coding-question-that-you-faced-in-an-interview/answer/Lalit-Kundu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to solve this problem. Let `f(i, j)` be the smallest lexicographical path (after sorting the path) from `(i, j)` to `(N, M)` moving only right and down. Consider the following recurrence:

```
f(i, j) = sort( a(i, j) + smallest(f(i + 1, j), f(i, j + 1)))
```

where `a(i, j)` is the value in the grid at `(i, j)`, `smallest (x, y)` returns the smaller lexicographical string between `x` and `y`. the `+` concatenate two strings, and `sort(str)` sorts the string `str` in lexical order.

The base case of the recurrence is:

```
f(N, M) = a(N, M)
```

Also the recurrence change when `i = N` or `j = M` (make sure that you see that).

Consider the following code written in `C++`:

```
//-- the 200 is just the array size. It can be modified

string a[200][200];             //-- represent the input grid
string f[200][200];             //-- represent the array used for memoization
bool calculated[200][200];      //-- false if we have not calculate the value before, and true if we have
int N = 199, M = 199;           //-- Number of rows, Number of columns


//-- sort the string str and return it
string srt(string &str){
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}


//-- return the smallest of x and y
string smallest(string & x, string &y){
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
        if (x[i] < y[i]) return x;
        if (x[i] > y[i]) return y;
    }
    return x;
}



string solve(int i, int j){
    if (i == N && j == M) return a[i][j];       //-- if we have reached the buttom right cell (I assumed the array is 1-indexed
    if (calculated[i][j]) return f[i][j];       //-- if we have calculated this before 
    string ans;
    if (i == N) ans = srt(a[i][j] + solve(i, j + 1));       //-- if we are at the buttom boundary
    else if (j == M) ans = srt(a[i][j] + solve(i + 1, j));  //-- if we are at the right boundary
    else ans = srt(a[i][j] + smallest(solve(i, j + 1), solve(i + 1, j)));       
    calculated[i][j] = true;        //-- to fetch the calculated result in future calls
    f[i][j] = ans;
    return ans;
}


string calculateSmallestPath(){
    return solve(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you give a code for this? It's difficult to understand.

Comment: Check the code I posted, and if you have any question, do not hesitate.

Comment: Ok I implemented your code, but it didn't print anything :( ideone link- http://ideone.com/2mc5NA

Comment: sorry, I had a bug in the base case. Try now

Comment: http://ideone.com/2mc5NA It's not working... fork this code maybe and then debug your solution? It also has an input, the answer to which is 1 2 4

Comment: http://ideone.com/nH81DQ. You did not change my last edit, and the array was 0-indexed while my code assumes that the array is 1-indexed.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry, Thank you so much for the explanation.Got it now, and it really helped :)

Comment: What is the time complexity for this approach??

Comment: @SrikiranSistla It should be `O(N * M * max(N, M) * log(N))` Since for each pair (i, j) you are doing one sort operation which takes `O(max(N, M) * log(N))`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a dynamic programming approach to solve this problem in `O(N * M * (N + M))` time and space complexity.

Below I'll consider, that `N` is the number of rows, `M` is the number of columns, and top left cell has coordinates `(0, 0)`, first for row and second for column.

Lets for each cell store the lexicographically smallest path ended at this cell in sorted order. The answer for row and column with `0` index is trivial, because there is only one way to reach each of these cells. For the rest of cells you should choose the smallest path for top and left cells and insert the value of current cell.

The algorithm is:

```
path[0][0] <- a[0][0]
path[i][0] <- insert(a[i][0], path[i - 1][0])
path[0][j] <- insert(a[0][j], path[0][j - 1])
path[i][j] <- insert(a[i][j], min(path[i - 1][j], path[i][j - 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If no number is repeated, this can be achieved in `O (NM log (NM))` as well.

**Intuition:**

Suppose I label a grid with upper left corner `(a,b)` and bottom right corner `(c,d)` as `G(a,b,c,d)`. Since you've to attain the lexicographically smallest string **AFTER** sorting the path, the aim should be to find the minimum value every time in `G`. If this minimum value is attained at, let's say, `(i,j)`, then `G(i,b,c,j)` and `G(a,j,i,d)` are rendered useless for the search of our next min (for the path). That is to say, the values for the path we desire would never be in these two grids. Proof? Any location within these grids, if traversed will not let us reach the minimum value in `G(a,b,c,d)` (the one at `(i,j)`). And, if we avoid `(i,j)`, the path we build **cannot** be lexicographically smallest.

[image]

So, first we find the min for `G(1,1,m,n)`. Suppose it's at `(i,j)`. Mark the min. We then find out the **min** in `G(1,1,i,j)` and `G(i,j,m,n)` and do the same for them. Keep continuing this way until, at the end, we have `m+n-1` marked entries, which will constitute our path. Traverse the original grid `G(1,1,m,n)` linearly and the report the value if it is marked.

**Approach:**

To find the min every time in `G` is costly. What if we map each value in the grid to it's location? - Traverse the grid and maintain a dictionary `Dict` with the key being the value at `(i,j)` and the value being the tuple `(i,j)`. At the end, you'll have a list of key value pairs covering all the values in the grid.

Now, we'll be maintaining a list of valid grids in which we will find candidates for our path. The first valid grid will be `G(1,1,m,n)`.

Sort the keys and start iterating from the first value in the sorted key set `S`.

Maintain a tree of valid grids, `T(G)`, such that for each `G(a,b,c,d) in T`, `G.left = G(a,b,i,j)` and `G.right = G(i,j,c,d)` where `(i,j) = location of min val in G(a,b,c,d)`

The algorithm now:

```
for each val in sorted key set S do
    (i,j) <- Dict(val)
    Grid G <- Root(T)
    do while (i,j) in G
       if G has no child do
           G.left <- G(a,b,i,j)
           G.right <- G(i,j,c,d)
       else if (i,j) in G.left
           G <- G.left
       else if (i,j) in G.right
           G <- G.right
       else 
           dict(val) <- null
           end do
       end if-else
    end do
end for
for each val in G(1,1,m,n)
    if dict(val) not null
        solution.append(val)
    end if
end for
return solution
```

The Java code:

```
class Grid{
    int a, b, c, d;
    Grid left, right;
    Grid(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        left = right = null;
    }
    public boolean isInGrid(int e, int f){
        return (e >= a && e <= c && f >= b && f <= d);
    }
    public boolean hasNoChild(){
        return (left == null && right == null);
    }
}
public static int[] findPath(int[][] arr){
        int row = arr.length;
        int col = arr[0].length;
        int[][] index = new int[row*col+1][2];
        HashMap<Integer,Point> map = new HashMap<Integer,Point>();
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                map.put(arr[i][j], new Point(i,j));
            }
        }
        Grid root = new Grid(0,0,row-1,col-1);
        SortedSet<Integer> keys = new TreeSet<Integer>(map.keySet());
        for(Integer entry : keys){
            Grid temp = root;
            int x = map.get(entry).x, y = map.get(entry).y;
            while(temp.isInGrid(x, y)){
                if(temp.hasNoChild()){
                    temp.left = new Grid(temp.a,temp.b,x, y);
                    temp.right = new Grid(x, y,temp.c,temp.d);
                    break;
                }
                if(temp.left.isInGrid(x, y)){
                    temp = temp.left;
                }
                else if(temp.right.isInGrid(x, y)){
                    temp = temp.right;
                }
                else{
                    map.get(entry).x = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        int[] solution = new int[row+col-1];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                if(map.get(arr[i][j]).x >= 0){
                    solution[count++] = arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return solution;
    }
```

The space complexity is constituted by maintenance of dictionary - `O(NM)` and of the tree - `O(N+M)`. Overall: `O(NM)`

The time complexity for filling up and then sorting the dictionary - `O(NM log(NM))`; for checking the tree for each of the `NM` values - `O(NM log(N+M))`. Overall - `O(NM log(NM))`.

Of course, this won't work if values are repeated since then we'd have more than one `(i,j)`'s for a single value in the grid and the decision to chose which will no longer be satisfied by a greedy approach.

Additional FYI: The problem similar to this I heard about earlier had an additional grid property - there are no values repeating and the numbers are from `1 to NM`. In such a case, the complexity could further reduce to `O(NM log(N+M))` since instead of a dictionary, you can simply use values in the grid as indices of an array (which won't required sorting.)

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of the log factor?